# is there a component for a small drop down menu

Tags: iphone, ios, drop-down-menu

I've searched but haven't found exactely what I'm looking for. The app MyDataMgr has a very nice animated drop down menu (see pic). Does anyone know, if there this is an available component or where something similar can be found?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: No. This is a regular UITableView with frame smaller then your main view's frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no component(as shown in image) provided by Apple.
Instead use UITableVIew, and when you touch setting button set your table view frame in an animation block

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"bringTableDown" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
tblTime.frame =CGRectMake(222, 97, 84, 160);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Note:- You have to give table a frame, if you are creating programmatically.

OR use blocks

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
     tblTime.frame =CGRectMake(222, 97, 84, 160);

}];
```

Comment: Just a hint, but using animations like this stopped being advised by Apple when UIKit animation blocks were added in iOS 4. You should look into them :)

Comment: Thanks, also added block animation

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge goes there is not but i have implemented something similar using `UITableView` and animation just change the rect of table view in animation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a custom table view.

You can use [**NIDropdown**](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/nidropdown) open source control for doing this.